# Why can't I save as picture? (Word 2010)

Tags: microsoft-word, images, save-as

I have some images in a Word document that I want to save. However, the 'Save as Picture' option that usually appears when you right-click on an image in Word is not available:

[image: Right-click menu on image]

My images are in a table - does this make a difference? I have tried moving them out of the table but the save option still isn't there.

Comment: It looks as though you have highlighted the frame, not the image. Have you tried copy/paste?

Comment: Interesting...I have tried right-clicking all over it, including as close to the edge as possible, but can't work out how to highlight the actual picture instead. If I paste it into another Word doc, it looks the same and still doesn't have the save option on right-click.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the inclusion of "Edit Points" in the context menu, I'd say that graphic is [SmartArt](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/word2013/28) and/or a form of Shape, and not just an embedded image.

> **Save your picture or SmartArt graphic as a .gif, .png, or .jpg file**
>
> You can save a picture or SmartArt graphic in a graphics file format
>   such as Graphics Interchange Format (.gif), JPEG File Interchange
>   Format (.jpg), or Portable Network Graphics Format (.png).
>
> 1. Click the picture or SmartArt graphic that you want to save in a graphics file format.
> 2. On the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click Copy.
> 3. On the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click the arrow under Paste, and then click Paste Special.
> 4. In the Paste Special dialog box, in the As list, click Picture (GIF), Picture (PNG), or Picture (JPEG).
> 5. Right-click the graphic, and then click Save as Picture.
> 6. Type a name for your graphic file, browse to the location where you want to save the file, and then click Save.

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HA103374159990&lcid=1033&NS=WINWORD&Version=12&respos=0&queryid=6ebbf378%2D5646%2D4532%2D85fb%2D3801437d0942#_Toc278804436)

Answer (score 3):

You can also save the picture using the following basic steps:

1. Save the document as a webpage [image: save dialog]
2. Open the webpage and save the picture, [image: browser with image open]

Comment: very innovative.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 is very good, the only thing I would add is that you may also be able to:

1. Ungroup the Object - note, all parts of it will become Selected when you've done this
2. Change your selection so that only the "pure" graphic is selected - this may be awkward, welcome to Word
3. You may now be able to Save as picture - or you may find that a few levels of grouping have been done

I was going to add this as a comment but I can't atm because I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

easy solution.... use your snipping tool to capture the image then paste it back into the same document...that will then allow you to make it a saved picture by right clicking or save it from within the snip tool to a picture.